# R Workspace and creating a factor variable from a numeric variable

Tags: r

I am a new beginner learning R. My question should be related to either R's Workspace or creating a factor variable or both. Here is my problem: I used this syntax to open a csv file titled "lecturerData":

```
lecturerData <- read.csv("Lecturer Data.csv" , header = TRUE)
```

This file has a column titled "job" which has two neumwric values: 1 and 2. I want to change these values to a factor variable so that 1 represents Lecturer and 2 represent Student. So, I used this syntax:

`job <- factor (job, levels = c(1:2), labels=c("Lecturer","Student"))`

But I receive this error message:

```
object 'job' not found
```

Then I changed the above syntax to:

```
lecturerData$job <- factor (lecturerData$job, levels = c(1:2),
                            labels=c("Lecturer","Student"))
```

And it works. I feel that I am missing something here.

Would appreciate your help.

Comment: perhaps you should select an answer and accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Because *job* is a column of the `data.frame` *lecturerData*, the R session doesnt know anything about the *job* column without information about *lecturerData*. The `$` tells it to look in *lecturerData*.

Here's the relevant section of an introduction manual:
http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Lists-and-data-frames

Answer (score 0):

In

```
job <- factor (job, levels = c(1:2), labels=c("Lecturer","Student"))
```

you are trying to call a variable that has yet to be created that explains the error.

If you did something like

```
job <- lecturerData[,(inserts column number for job)]
```

then run the code above should solve your problem

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few examples of how to create a `data.frame` and then a `factor()` variable.

```
# Create a data frame

df <- data.frame(x = 1:1000, y = rnorm(1000, 100, 20))

# Take a look at it
head(df)
names(df)
str(df)

# Convert a numerical variable to a factor variable
# check out ?cut
# also ?rnorm

df$z <- cut(df$y, breaks = c(0, 50, 100, 200, 1000000) )

df$binary <- ifelse(df$y < 100, 1 , 0)

str(df)
# Now binary is numeric
# If i just type binary i'm R doesn't know in which data.frame it is.

df$binary_factor <- factor(df$binary, levels = 1:2, labels = c("lecturer", "student") )

# Take a look at it again
head(df)
names(df)
str(df)

# Agreggate
# Check out ?table

table <- table(df$z)

plot(df$z)

library(ggplot2)
qplot(df$y, binwidth = 0.5, fill = df$z)
qplot(df$z, fill = df$z)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use transform() to avoid having to do the $ syntax:

```
lecturerData <- transform(lecturerData,
    job = factor(job, levels = c(1:2), labels=c("Lecturer","Student"))
)
```